# Query for when my service will be run in Android?

Tags: android, service, receiver

I have a service that fires off every 5 minutes or so... How would i query android to see when this service is scheduled to go off programatically?

```
    <!-- Send Census Service -->
    <service android:name="services.scheduled.SendCensusScheduledService"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="SyncServerDataScheduledService" />
    <receiver android:name="services.receivers.SendCensusScheduledServiceReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ReceiptBucketClient.android.action.broadcast"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="services.receivers.StartSendCensusScheduledServiceReceiver" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check by the `PendingIntent`:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
        new Intent("ReceiptBucketClient.android.action.broadcast"), 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE;

if (intent != null) {
   // you have the service scheduled. Cancel it!
   intent.cancel();
}
```

Remember that [only the original application owning a PendingIntent can cancel it.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#cancel())